# Load stashy.offcanvas with asp.net SPA Hot Towel Template

Tags: asp.net, web

I have searched a lot but I could not find any materials to implement stashy.offcanvas to Hot Towel template. Anyone has any tutorial which could assist me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I´m not sure if you are talking about my own library [Stashy](https://github.com/yagopv/stashy), but if you are, i  implemented it [here](https://durandalauth.azurewebsites.net/#home/articles) ... it´s not Hot Towel but it´s pretty much the same (Durandal, Breeze and ASP MVC + Web Api).

You can find the code i used [here (js)](https://github.com/yagopv/DurandalAuth/blob/master/DurandalAuth.Web/App/viewmodels/home/articles.js) and [here (html)](https://github.com/yagopv/DurandalAuth/blob/master/DurandalAuth.Web/App/views/home/articles.html), and some required CSS [over here (the #article section)](https://github.com/yagopv/DurandalAuth/blob/master/DurandalAuth.Web/Content/app.css)

Hope this helps if is about what you a talking about :)